# Ratchet onopen client not fire

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, reactphp

I am trying to implement Ratchet Socket [Hello word](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) on my local machine every things works perfectly but on vps centos server when i run server service with

```
ssh Command : php chat-server.php
```

it start Listening on port correctly(i can see on linux that port is Listening ) ,  but when i open "clint.html" page the method `onopen` never fire but server says

> new client connected !

and after 2 minute it says

> client disconnected

if i send message to client it will take 2 minutes then client will receive it, but it will disconnect again
it seems to me that there is not stable connection between server and client. every time when i check websocket.readyState its not equal to 1  
i disabled firewall and any security on vps server but still have this problem.
i have to mention that normal php socket functions works without problem because i could test it  and [every thing works](http://www.abrandao.com/2013/06/websockets-html5-php/)
 but about ratchet it seems it  hang on `onopen` method.

- port 9091 is open
- firewall is disabled
- abrandao.com/2013/06/websockets-html5-php/ works whiteout problem and can send and receive message from clients
- BUT Ratchet has problem onconnect

  chat-server.php :

  ```
  use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
  use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
  use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
  use MyApp\Chat;
  require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $server = IoServer::factory(
      new HttpServer(
          new WsServer(
              new Chat()
          )
      ),
      9091
  );
  echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." chat-server Started on port 9091 \n";
  $server->run();
  ```

  Chat.php class :

  ```
  namespace MyApp;
  use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
  use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
  class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
  protected $clients;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;      
  }

  public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {        
      $this->clients->attach($conn);
      echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";        
      $conn->send("Hello {$conn->resourceId} from server at : ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
      echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." Hello Sent to  ({$conn->resourceId})\n"; 

  }

  public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
      $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
      echo sprintf(date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
          , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');
      foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
          if ($from !== $client) {                
              $client->send($msg);
          }
      }
  }

  public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {        
      $this->clients->detach($conn);
      echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
  }

  public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
      echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
      $conn->close();
  }
  }
  ```

  client html :

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
     connect();  
  });

  var wsUri = "ws://myserverdomain.comOrIP:9091";   


   function connect() {
    var ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);

    ws.onopen = function() {
      var now = new Date();
      console.log(now + ' Connected to '+wsUri);        
    };

    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
        var now = new Date();
      console.log(now + ' Message Recived From Server :', e.data);
    };

    ws.onclose = function(e) {
        var now = new Date();
      console.log(now +' Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second.', e.reason);
      setTimeout(function() {
        connect();
      }, 1000)
    };

    ws.onerror = function(err) {
        var now = new Date();
      console.error(now + ' Socket encountered error: ', err.message, 'Closing socket')
      console.error(err)
      ws.close()
    };
  }
  ```

Comment: Could you add what webserver you have running, nginx/apache/...? Since the connection closing after 2 minutes is probeably about those only being set to keep connections alive for 120 seconds

Comment: @mitchken Its Apache. and i changed max_timout to 1000 It does not matter .i changed Keep-Alive Timeout  , ... default_socket_timeout on php.ini and i tested alot of things .

Comment: @mitchken Its Apache running on centos linux. and i changed max_timeout to 1000 It does not matter .i changed Keep-Alive Timeout  , ... default_socket_timeout on php.ini and i tested a lot of things . its interesting for me why normal php socket works without problem but ratchet not working. i had to write my own websocket server  from scratch :( and now its running well . but did any one could run ratchet hello world simple app on linux before ? i think there must be a bug in ratchet script

Comment: I am running a ratchet PHP server with over 5K concurrrent connections.
I myself started by testing the hello world as well and it worked for me